# JavaScript Regular Expression For Usernames No Spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I am seeking help with a JavaScript RegEx for user names.  Basically I need the letters A-Z, digits, periods, dashes, underscores, dollar signs, at signs, the asterisk, and the exclamation point to be allowed and the username can be up to 30 characters long.  No spaces or commas should be allowed for example.

Allowed characters:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
.
-
_
$
@
*
!
```

- User.name = passes
- User name = fails
- User,name = fails
- usernameeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee = fails

Comment: This looks like a basic regex and you even know the format of char ranges. What's blocking you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `^[-\w\.\$@\*\!]{1,30}$`, where `1` and `30` are the bounds that you can change depending on how short the password needs to be at a minimum.

`\w` provides the Numbers, letters, and underscore coverage, followed by all the special chars you are allowing.  Make sure to properly escape the special chars since a lot of them are used in actual regex parsing.

Using your examples provided (and some extra ones) you can see the regex working [here](http://rubular.com/r/IQPnmvFwiB).

Answer (score 12):

The following should work:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_$@*!]{3,30}$/
```

Note that I also enforced a minimum length of 3 characters, change this to whatever you actually want.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5F5cQ/1/